# Update Gradient Color of cell once I select a cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

[enter image description here][1]I have added a gradient layer on the cell of table view. Now I want to update the colour of gradient layer once I tap on the particular cell.

```
func updateGradientColors(colors: [UIColor]) {
    if let layer = self.layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer {
        layer.colors = ColorUtils.cgColorsFromUIColor(colors: colors)
    }
}
```

So, once I called this `updateGradientColors` function in the `didSelect` delegate method, the layer with new color is not getting updating with proper frame.

I also tried by updating frame of gradient in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` function. But still it's not working fine

```
func updateGradientFrame() {
    if let layer = self.layer.sublayers?.first, layer is CAGradientLayer {
        layer.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQDIuYhRITlKLnBDKF1eo6CAXKj4-xgw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean with "color is not getting updated with proper frame"? The colours are as expected, but layer is out of frame?

Comment: Is `layer.colors = ColorUtils.cgColorsFromUIColor(colors: colors)` called when the cell is tapped? You don't change the frame, so why should it change? Are you sure it wasn't at first and because you used clear colors that you didn't see a frame issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints and checking to see if your code executes this line `layer.colors = ColorUtils.cgColorsFromUIColor(colors: colors)` ? is this line getting called?

Comment: Are you sure `self.layer.sublayers?.first` is your `CAGradientLayer`? This is pretty fragile - you would be better to have a `var gradientLayer` in your cell class

Comment: @AshleyMills yes self.layer.sublayers?.first is a CAGradientLyer

Comment: @regina_fallangi Please find the attached image